# Why isn't the function being called? C++

Tags: c++, function, class

Sorry if it's something stupid, I am just learning C++ and I couldn't find any reason why the function isnt being called.

I have this robot class and a function that has 2 class (robot) parameters, while I don't get any errors the check_S function never runs.

Also feel free to correct any bad practice you may see used in my code. Thanks

Partial code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class robot
{
    (.....)
};

    robot::robot()    
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        S = 0;
        E = 0;
        C = 0;
    }

void check_S(robot robot1, robot robot2);

int main() 
{
    robot robot1;
    robot robot2;

    void check_S(robot robot1, robot robot2);
}

void check_S(robot robot1, robot robot2)
{
    cout << " in the function  " << endl;
    if ( robot1.robot::get_x() == robot2.robot::get_x() || robot1.robot::get_y()      == robot2.robot::get_y()
         || (robot1.robot::get_x() - robot1.robot::get_y()) ==   (robot2.robot::get_x() - robot2.robot::get_y())
         || (robot1.robot::get_x() + robot1.robot::get_y()) == (robot2.robot::get_x() + robot2.robot::get_y())){

        robot1.robot::set_S(robot1.robot::get_S()+1);
        cout << " s changed to  " << robot1.S << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend moving the `check_S` function to a member function of `robot`.  This would eliminate the need for the `get_x()` and `get_y()` functions since the `x` and `y` data members can be accessed directly.

Comment: But if I move the `check_S` function would I still be able to compare `x` and `y` for two different `robot` objects? And also I need to call it at a specific time, how would I be able to, if I did that?

Comment: You would be able to do something like `robot_a.check_S(robot_b);`.

Comment: Oh I get it now! Looks easier indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
void check_S(robot robot1, robot robot2);
```

is a function declaration (because of the type names before the function name and arguments), not a function call. 
To call the function, write:

```
check_S(robot1, robot2);
```

Comment: Tried it, it returns this error 
error: variable or field 'check_S' declared void

Comment: Barmar that was the mistake indeed. Thank you!